# How to set your own $args in Wordpress default-tags?

Tags: php, wordpress, tags, widget

I found a problem, my tags contains numbers. But i don't want that tags cloud show them. how to exclude tags, but the solution is adding a filter. 
My goal is to set up $args before the tags_cloud is called.
How to modify default-widgets.php or create work around for this?

```
wp_tag_cloud( apply_filters( 'widget_tag_cloud_args', array(
        'taxonomy' => $current_taxonomy
    ) ) );
```

Can you demystify this? How to add my own $args properties correctly? Where is $current_taxonomy created?

Answer (score 0):

`wp_tag_cloud()` already accepts arguments for `taxonomy` (as a string or array) and `exclude` (as a comma-separated list of `term_id`s to exclude):

```
$args = array(
    'taxonomy' => 'some_registered_taxonomy',
    'exclude' => '3,65,2',
);
wp_tag_cloud( $args );
```

More info [in the Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_tag_cloud).

Comment: I my case, I want to set up regexp to exclude tags containing numbers. Is it good practice to edit default-widgets.php or its better to create filter in my theme child's functions.php to set args for wp_tag_cloud(). Shown file is located in wp-includes/default-widgets.php.